# xpath not working with certain id

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am quite new to Selenium and I am learning everything at once, sometimes I still struggles with HTML notation.

I searched a lot in the internet, documentation but no success so far. I have the html code below, where I want to call the script related to the highlighted "Voltar" button. Here you can find the HTML code snippet:
[image]

All of my attempts are not working, how can I click on that "Voltar" button?

Please, only Python code.

Comment: *All of my attempts are not working*... Show those attempts. Share exception log also

Comment: Andersson, I am new to this and I have no idea on how to log it.
Can you provide me some guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution you want.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(your_url)
commit_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Voltar']")
commit_value.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# when you are done, don't forget to close driver
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to find the element with selenium I'd do something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@value="Voltar"]')
```

The * represents any tag 
 The @ represents an attribute and it's value.
So basically find any element that has a value attribute equal to 'Voltar'.

Comment: This is not Python code

Comment: Now it is. @Andersson

Comment: Nope. It still not. There is no such method as `findElement()`